# C - macro is defined based on type name

Tags: c, macros, typedef

I'm working on a task which has a macro of the following form.

```
// Thread identifier type.
typedef int tid_t;
#define TID_ERROR ((tid_t) -1)          /* Error value for tid_t. */
```

Then, some functions having the type tid_t will return that macro in case of failure:

```
tid_t foo()
{
  if(fail())
  {
    return TID_ERROR;
  }
}
```

I can't understand how this makes sense:

a)How can a constant be subtracted from a type name `tid_t - 1`?

b)How can the previous result be returned? I thought types are not data, so they can't be manipulated in the same manner.

And, what I need to know:

c)When calling the function `foo`, how can I check for failure?

Answer (score 3):

It's not returning or manipulating a type, it's returning the *value* `-1`, cast to that type.

To check for the error, compare with the TID_ERROR macro.

```
tid_t result = foo();
if(result == TID_ERROR) { handle error }
```

Answer (score 3):

```
#define TID_ERROR ((tid_t) -1)
```

It's not subtracting `1` from `tid_t`, it's a cast, to cast `-1` to the type `tid_t`, which is then used as an invalid value for this type.

Answer (score 0):

when the compiler compiles this code:

```
tid_t foo()
{
   if(fail())
   {
       return TID_ERROR;
   }
}
```

it equals this code:

```
int foo()
{
   if(fail())
   {
       return ((int) -1); // just change the type of `-1` to `int` type.
   }
}
```